# Regular expression for DSL

Tags: ruby, regex, rubular

I'm trying to write a regular expression that captures two groups: the first is group of n words (where n>= 0 and it's variable) and the second is a group of pairs with this format `field:value`. In both groups, the individuals are separated by blank spaces. Eventually, an optional space separates the two groups (unless one of them is blank/nil).

Please, take into consideration the following examples:

```
'the big apple'.match(pattern).captures # => ['the big apple', nil]
'the big apple is red status:drafted1 category:3'.match(pattern).captures # => ['the big apple is red', 'status:drafted1 category:3']
'status:1'.match(pattern).captures # => [nil, 'status:1']
```

I have tried a lot of combinations and patterns but I can't get it working. My closest pattern is `/([[\w]*\s?]*)([\w+:[\w]+\s?]*)/`, but it doesn't work properly in the second and third case previously exposed.

Thanks!

Comment: Are the serie of word and the field:value format always in that order ?

Comment: asiny the desired result is already in the question! Look at the _following examples_ :D

Comment: yes, always the words come first!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one regex solution:

```
 (.*?)(?:(?: ?((?: ?\w+:\w+)+))|$)
```

- `(.*?)` match anythings but is not greedy and is used to find words
- then there is a group or the end of line `$`
- the group ignore the space `?` then match all `field:value` with `\w+:\w+`

See an example here https://regex101.com/r/nZ9wU6/1 (I had flags to show the behavior but it works best for single result)

Comment: You're my man! It worked perfectly. Can you explain little more what `?:` does and how the solution behaves? It seems magic to me : D

Comment: it was a hard one but fun to do :D had to redo it 4 times to match perfectly all cases

Answer (score 1):

Not a regexp, but give it a try

```
string = 'the big apple:something'
first_result = ''
second_result = ''

string.split(' ').each do |value|
  value.include?(':') ? first_string += value : second_string += value
end
```

Comment: Thanks! But I'm trying to solve it with regexp. Anyways, I've voted positive because you proposed a _valid but alternative_ solution!